# Can't get JTDS drivers to work in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sql-server-2012, oracle-sqldeveloper, jtds

I am very inexperienced and without appropriate training so apologies if I don't phrase this right or include enough information.

I am attempting to connect a SQL server (Accessed typically via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) to a data warehouse via Oracle SQL Developer.  But I just can't get SQL developer to recognise the JTDS drivers to enable the SQL Connection.  I have downloaded multiple versions of the driver (Jtds1.2.2 and Jtds1.3.1) and I have used the Tools/Preferences/Database/Third Party JDBC drivers tab to specify their location.  But I never get a SQL connection option in the connection dialogue.  There are no error messages produced, it just never seems to do anything.

The goal of my efforts is to be able to directly access the data warehouse from our SQL server.

I have watched numerous videos showing this process working and I can't work out what is going wrong.  The Oracle website suggests that these drivers can be installed via the Check for Updates function but this doesn't do anything when I have attempted it.

Comment: Grab 1.3.1, but the jars in your sqldev home folder, point to those jars in the preferences, then restart sqldev.

Comment: I don't understand "connect a SQL server (Accessed typically via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) to a data warehouse _via Oracle SQL Developer_"  Normally you'd simply create a 'shared server' within the mssql database, pointing to the oracle db.  Then the tables in the oracle db are accessible to mssql, just like any table within the mssql db.

Comment: Why use the outdated (and I think not maintained anymore) jTDS driver and not the current Microsoft JDBC driver?

Comment: Thank you all.  It appear the directory was an issue.  
@EdStevens I was hoping that would be possible.  But the warehouse administrator told us we had to go through SQL developer.

Comment: @GRog Great work finding a solution.  Please post your solution as an answer below and feel free to accept it.  This will let the community know you solved it.  Great work!

Comment: "warehouse administrator told us we had to go through SQL developer"  I'd love to know his reasoning.  SQL Deveoper is 'just another client'.  A shared server from mssql is 'just another client'.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to Copy the drivers into the same parent directory as the SQL developer.  Previously I had tried copying it inside one of the sub folders and tried copying it outside of the directory.  But as soon as I put it in the main SQL developer folder it worked.

Thanks to thatjeffsmith